# How to tweet picture with text

Tags: javascript, php, twitter

I want to share my app images in Twitter.
I want to tweet picture with text using Javascript and php and Twitter Api's with callback functions.
How can i do this?

I have tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.twitterbutton.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#twitterbutton-example').twitterbutton({
            user: 'POSimplicity',
            title: ' powered by POSimplicity',
            count_url: false,
            user_description: 'user description',
            url: 'http://www.abc.in/index.php',
            ontweet: function (response) {
                var id = $("p").html();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'add_customer.php',
                    data: 'twitpoints=' + '<?php echo $res['
                    0 ']['
                    regpoints ']; ?>' + '&total_points=' + '30' + '&customer_id=' + id,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (res) {
                        alert(res);
                    }
                });
            },
            lang: 'en'
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this i am able to tweet URL but not images.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Even Google doesn't answer that, so I don't think that comment is appropriate here..

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I agree with mr alien skimming the twitter api there is no mention of embeding images with the tweet

Comment: https://blog.twitter.com/2011/photo-upload-api

Comment: real work goes to @Derek朕會功夫 https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media using a media[] array you can apparently upload a media asset image only using the post method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this twitter API to upload images with tweet : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media

updated link:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Also, the link is broken